# "Listening" to a field change with eventhandler outside of the object the field belongs to

Tags: c#, events, listener, event-listener

I'm working on a C# project-module that is designed to be able to sort of be "attached" to different projects. By including it into a namespace, the user will be able to instantiate an object of the `MonitoringModule`-type.
This object is in place to be able to write devices to that it should "monitor". I'm keeping track of a device-type enum, when a device is given to the MonitoringModule it'll expect a device-type parameter to know what fields it should monitor on this device.
Every device extends the `IDevice` interface which forces it to have the standard device fields (name and type, firmware version, serial nr, things like that). These fields are private, but have a global getter and setter. The global setter is written like this (Display is an example device-type):

```
public class Display : IDevice
{
    private string firmware;
    public event StateChangedEventHandler StateChanged;

    public string Firmware
    {
        get { return this.firmware; }
        set
        {
            this.firmware = value;
            this.OnStateChanged(new StateChangedEventArgs(this, "firmware"))
        }
    }
}
```

The MonitoringModule, in turn, has a listener, to which it's subscribed whenever prompted to monitor a new device

```
public class MonitoringModule
{
    public void addDevice(IDevice device, DeviceType.Display deviceType)
    {
        //add the device to monitoringmodule
        //maybe something deviceType specific
        device.StateChanged += new StateChangedEventHandler(device_stateChanged);
    }

    void device_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //here it does things with the received e.device and it's e.changedState
    {
}
```

This works perfectly as intended, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can do this without having to write the second like of the public Setter on all fields that need to be monitored, on all devices that need to be monitored. Comparing to the work that needed to be done before this, it's a very big improvement already, but I want to take it the extra mile and remove all handwritten changes necessary to implement this module.
So far I've managed to find [this](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/69047468-66aa-43c2-bbf5-4236f8d1e1e8.htm) website that seems to be on the right track of what I'm looking for but it feels like I'm missing something in the explanation because I do not completely understand how it works.

Comment: This already exists as `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Be very weary of  rolling your own.

Comment: @bommelding I don't think INotifyPropertyChanged does anything different from what I did by declaring my own `EventHandler` and `EventArgs`, because I'd still need to write the `PropertyChanged()` in my setters..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. Have you `IDevice` implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). (read the link)

Do all the devices have the same properties, that you want to watch?
Then have a base class do it: `class abstract DeviceBase : IDevice`

You can also write you own `Set` method, that does spare you thwo lines of code in each setter. The MVVM light toolkit has such a method: http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/4162331c-43b6-7806-f488-8f6426aa0304.htm